# Setting menu items css font style has no visible effect

Tags: css, javafx, menuitem, font-style

I would like to change the MenuItem's text to bold when the user clicks on it. To manage to do this I'm using `setStyle`, but unfortunately it has no visible effect. The css makes no effect when the user selects the MenuItem option. The css styling only has an effect in initialize method.

I created a minimal reproducible example for the problem:

**MAIN:**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public final class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainView.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 850.0, 650.0);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**MAIN FXML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>

<BorderPane  prefHeight="475.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 
fx:controller="MainController">
    <top>
      <MenuBar BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <menus>
          <Menu fx:id="menu" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Switch Chart">
            <items>
              <MenuItem text="MenuItem1" />
              <MenuItem onAction="#setFontBold" text="MenuItem2" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
        </menus>
      </MenuBar>
   </top>
</BorderPane>
```

**MAIN CONTROLLER:**

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;

public class MainController implements Initializable {
    @FXML private Menu menu;

    private List<MenuItem> menuItems;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        menuItems = menu.getItems();
        menuItems.get(0).setStyle("-fx-font-weight: bold");
    }

    public void setFontBold() {
        menuItems.get(1).setStyle("-fx-font-weight: bold");
        System.out.println(menuItems.get(1).getStyle());
        System.out.println("Font set to bold in menuitem with index 1 has no effect...");
    }
}
```

So I get the following css effects, even after selecting the first indexed menu item (so onAction=#setFontBold not changes anything visually).

[No bold effect. - only if you set the style in initialize()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csSf6.png)

I'm curious about why it makes no difference? It definitely sets the style to bold, but it is displayed as a regular font even after changing it to bold.

**EDIT:** JavaFX version: 8.0.211-b10

Comment: worksforme .. check if this is really the code you are running: a bit suspicious that it throws a NPE in initialize (because the id of the menu in the fxml incorrectly starts with a capital letter)

Comment: Yes, you are right. I forgot to edit that out. Now it's fine. Even though, the MenuItem with the text MenuItem2 stays in regular font for me (even after I click on it). It really works for you? Then why don't for me? @kleopatra

Comment: no idea - which version do you have? mine is fx11 - hach missed your edit: yeah, than it might be a bug that's fixed meanwhile .. didn't check, though. Most probably it's a missing listener in the skin bowels of ContextMenu/Container: need one to update the style of the control if they are changed on the MenuItem (which is _not_ a control) But again, didn't check :)

Comment: yeah, the MenuItemContainer (parent for a single MenuLabel) sets the style initially only (fx) without any effort to keep it sync'd, in later version (fx11) it binds the style property to the item's style

Comment: Thank you again for helping me out kleopatra. I planned to upgrade my javafx version anyway. There are some obvious reasons that I should do that.

Answer (score 0):

If I would have to stick to javafx 8 and switching was the requirement, I would have used RadioMenuItem. It does the job as expected, but does not make MenuItem text bold.

From official docs, I found following excerpt that would be useful.

```
ToggleGroup toggleGroup = new ToggleGroup();

RadioMenuItem radioItem1 = new RadioMenuItem("Option 1");
radioItem.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
@Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
    System.out.println("radio toggled");
}
});
radioItem1.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);
RadioMenuItem radioItem2 = new RadioMenuItem("Option 2");
radioItem.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
@Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
    System.out.println("radio toggled");
}
});

radioItem2.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);
```